# What is the difference between a probability mass function and discrete probability distribution?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

As stated in wiki, A "discrete probability distribution" is a probability distribution characterized by a "probability mass function". Are both terms synonymous or there is some difference between two terms. I have seen both of them used interchangeably across many textbooks. 
Although this question have been asked before, but I could not find any right answer in that discussion. 
Please Help.

Comment: Even if there is any grammatical difference between the two, do tell.

Comment: First of all you have a random variable. We say the random variable follows a certain (parametric) distribution if and only if its cumulative distribution function has a certain (parametric) form. For a discrete random variable, its probability mass function, as stated in wiki, can also uniquely characterize a distribution. E.g. we say $X$ has a $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ distribution if and only if $\Pr\{X = 1\} = p, \Pr\{X = 0\} = 1 - p$, and $\Pr\{X = x\} = 0$ otherwise. So in terms of characterizing a discrete distribution, its name and pmf serve the same purpose

Comment: However, pmf is a function but you will not call a function as ".... distribution". Some textbook question will ask you to determine the distribution of a certain random variable, which implicitly request you to compute the unknown cdf/pmf (or pdf)/mgf (if exist)/cf for such random variable and then compare with the well known distributions. As a conclusion you can have many ways to characterize a distribution, but I think  "used interchangeably" is an overstatement.